# Camel ProducerTemplate.asyncSendBody result in NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-camel, stack-trace

I have encountered issue when trying to invoke camel's producerTemplate.asyncSendBody(), producerTemplate.asyncSend() or recepientList(..) under high transaction rate. ***Sometime***, a NullPointerException is throw without a stacktrace. Am I doing something wrong with Camel? How could I get rid of this and get the proper stacktrace? Thanks in advance

***Below are the code of my simplified test cases***

CamelTest.java

```
public class CamelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1").process(new SendProcessor());
                from("direct:test").threads(10, 40).process(new PrintProcessor());
            }
        });

        camelContext.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(300);
        camelContext.stop();

    }

}
```

SendProcessor.java

```
public class SendProcessor implements Processor {

    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        if (producerTemplate == null) {
            producerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
        }

        final ProducerTemplate producer = producerTemplate;

        while (true) {
            producer.asyncSendBody("direct:test", ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10));
        }

    }

}
```

PrintProcessor.java

```
public class PrintProcessor implements Processor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CamelTest.class);

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Integer body = exchange.getIn().getBody(Integer.class);

        if (body.intValue() == 10) {
            LOGGER.info(exchange.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Exception Log

```
[Camel (camel-1) thread #14 - Threads] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-LEWIS-PC-50356-1449641197766-0-8156425 on ExchangeId: ID-LEWIS-PC-50356-1449641197766-0-8156426). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.NullPointerException

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route2            ] [route2            ] [direct://test                                                                 ] [         0]
[route2            ] [threads1          ] [threads                                                                       ] [         0]
[route2            ] [process2          ] [Processor@0x42cfc037                                                          ] [         0]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-LEWIS-PC-50356-1449641197766-0-8156426
    ExchangePattern     InOnly
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-LEWIS-PC-50356-1449641197766-0-8156425, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
    BodyType            Integer
    Body                5
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: please provide full stacktrace of NPE

Comment: This is already the full stack I got

Comment: I'm not sure why the whole stack trace is not being printed, but the next thing I would try is putting a try-catch in your processor. Seems like that's where the error is originating from.

Comment: I have tried the try-catch before, either in the processor or by using the EIP onException cause. However, the stacktrace is still missing

Comment: Have you tried to debug this in your ide to see where the nullpointer is set?

Comment: I can't reproduce that in debug mode. I suspect it is some kind of threading issue